# Javascript basics for Anguar component communication

Tags: javascript, angular, function

I have a code snippet from a colleague for the Angular component communication.

here is the **stackblitz**
https://angular-component-communication-by-input.stackblitz.io

I've always used Angular's @Input/@Output for component communication.
I want to understand why his solution is working and what are the correct Javascript terminologies to describe what he did.

1. He defined a function in the parent component

```
 eventHandler(...args){
    console.log(args)
  }
```

2. He passes the function to the child component

`<app-child [clickHandler]="eventHandler"></app-child>`

What confuses me is the use of `eventHandler`. Why is it not used as **`eventHandler()`**?

What is happening here? Please include some Javascript basics for the explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is passing a function by reference, basicly saying "here is a reference to the function", and on the child component, he is getting that referece and calling it to execute whatever function is being refered.

Like this simples example

```js
const example = console.log;
example('Hello'); // this would be the same as saying console.log('Hello')
```